# Load GeoServer WFS feature layer by block in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wfs, features

I have a WFS layer on GeoServer with more than 260,000 features, which contains data from an entire municipality. Thus, it takes a long time to load the entire layer on the map.

To test, I used a filter and it was possible to load part of the data.  However, I need to load everything.

Is it possible to load the layer by blocks, that is, as you drag the map / screen, do you load the values? I'm using OpenLayers version 5.

[CODE EDITED]

This is the version that works, with filter. I want to switch to using bbox, it loads new features from GeoServer WFS when view span changes. What do I need to change? Need to transform extend?

```
var my_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    visible: false,
    style: my_style,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
            return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MY_LAYER_CITY&' +
              '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
              'CQL_FILTER=COD_SETOR = '+value_setor+'&' +
              'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    })
});
```

All tests below did not work.
Using ol.proj.transformExtent
I made the changes suggested in the comments. It does not show the data and the OSM base is still deformed.

Obs: The following code works for one layer, but not for another. Could it be some setting? Any idea?

```
var my_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    visible: false,
    style: my_style,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
            const new_extend = ol.proj.transformExtent(extend.bbox, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
            return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MY_LAYER_CITY&' +
              '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
              'bbox=' + new_extent + ',EPSG:3857';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    })
});
```

I also changed according to the code https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/vector-wfs.html?q=wfs, however, nothing shows the data.
Observation, I only managed with filter and EPSG:4326&.

```
    var my_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    visible: false,
    style: my_style,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
            return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MY_LAYER_CITY&' +
              '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
              'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    })
});
```

Does anyone know what can it be? Where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: Use `strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox`.

Comment: Where is the layer `strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all`, change it to `strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox`?
In the layer, I won't have the filter either `'CQL_FILTER=NAME_B = '+value_filter+'`. I made those changes, but it didn't load the layer.

Comment: OpenLayers passes the extent to the url function in view projection.  You will need change the `+ ',EPSG:4326';` or transform the extent to EPSG:4326 (and to Lat Lon order)

Comment: @Mike I didn't understand. Could you explain to me "You will need change the + ',EPSG:4326'; or transform the extent to EPSG:4326 (and to Lat Lon order)"?

Comment: If the view projection is EPSG:3857 you would need `extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';`  Even if view projection is EPSG:4326 OpenLayers uses Lon Lat and WFS uses Lat Lon so you could not simply join the OpenLayers coordinate array (unlike EPSG:3857 where the order is always easting, northing)

Comment: Do you have some code/example of how I do this transformation, so that I can adapt to my layer? Because I am not able to solve it anyway.

Comment: Use `ol.proj.transformExtent`, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.transformExtent

Comment: I posted the code using ol.proj.transformExtent in the question, it didn't give an error, but it still didn't work.

Comment: You have also to request from GeoServer in this projection: `urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' + 'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MY_LAYER_CITY&' + '&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' + 'all=' + new_extent`.

Comment: TomazicM, I edited the code to include 3847, but I must have missed something. Does not show layer data

Comment: Instead of `'all=' + new_extent` put `'bbox=' + new_extent`.

Comment: I changed `'all=' + new_extent` to `'bbox=' + new_extent` and posted an image of the result in the question. Still not showing the data.

Comment: If the extent is already EPSG:3857 you do not need to transform it.  See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html

Comment: @Mike, it still didn't work. I don't know where the error is. I amended the question with the codes I tested.

Comment: @Mike, I followed the example in the link [openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html]. The code works for one layer, but not for another. Could it be some setting? Any idea?

Comment: If the service is strictly enforcing GeoJSON output format you shouldn't get any data if you request EPSG:3857 (because GeoJSON doesn't support that projection).    What data do you get if you make that request in a browser?

Comment: I don't get any data with bbox and or 3857. I only get data when I filter layer `'&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
 'CQL_FILTER=SECTOR_COD = '+sector_value+'&' +
  'all=' + extension.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';`

Comment: So you don't get the data is the issue, and nothing to do with OpenLayers not being able to display it.